# Update con MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo este código, pero no hace el update, y no sé porque.

```
<?php
// if ($_POST['accemail'] == "" || $_POST['accname'] == "" || $_POST['accphone'] == ""){
    // header("Location: myaccount.php");
// } else
// {
    include ("db_files/db.php");
    $strSQL = "UPDATE usuarios SET email = '".$_POST['accemail']."', nombre = '".$_POST['accname'] ."' razon_social = '".$_POST['accsocialreason']."', nif = '".$_POST['accnif']."', telefono = '".$_POST['accphone']."', direccion = '".$_POST['accaddress']."', ciudad = '".$_POST['acccity']."', provincia = '".$_POST['accprovince']."', codigo_postal = '".$_POST['acccp']."' pais = '".$_POST['acccountry']."' ";
    echo $strSQL;
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    // }

// }
?>
```

Me sale este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oneplayer_git\accupdate.php on line 15

No imprime la variable `$strSQL`

Comment: Hola Pavlo... ¿Te muestra algún mensaje de error? Prueba a hacer `echo $strSQL;` una vez generada la query y ejecútala directamente contra la base de datos ¿Arroja errores? ¿Funciona?

Comment: Para empezar, estás usando `if ($variable = "")` ... Debería ser `==` (doble signo), de lo contrario estás asignando, no comparando

Comment: Siguiendo unas líneas más, veo un terrible problema de seguridad que deberías evitar. Cualquiera podría borrarte toda la base de datos. Lee [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Comment: Y ahora comentaste las últimas `}` por demás (algo que sale en cualquier búsqueda de google con "unexpected end of file in")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo "escapar" los datos recibidos por POST para evitar inyecciones SQL http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Para escapar puedes usar la función real_escape_string(), te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['accemail'] == "" || $_POST['accname'] == "" || $_POST['accphone'] == ""){
    header("Location: myaccount.php");
 }else{

    include ("db_files/db.php");

    $post_accemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accemail']);
    $post_accname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accname']);
    $post_accsocialreason = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accsocialreason']);
    $post_accnif = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accnif']);
    $post_accphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accphone']);
    $post_accaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accaddress']);
    $post_acccity = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['acccity']);
    $post_accprovince = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['accprovince']);
    $post_acccp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['acccp']);
    $post_acccountry = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['acccountry']);


    $strSQL = "UPDATE usuarios SET email = '$post_accemail', nombre = '$post_accname'...
```

Al igual que te han comentado que no tienes la cláusula WHERE por lo cual, todos los registros de la tabla usuarios se verán afectados ya que no especificas que registro quieres que se actualize.

Answer (score 2):

Te faltan varias `,`, antes de `razon_social` y antes de `pais`.:

```
$strSQL = "UPDATE usuarios SET email = '".$_POST['accemail'].
"', nombre = '".$_POST['accname'] .
"' razon_social = '".$_POST['accsocialreason'].
"', nif = '".$_POST['accnif'].
"', telefono = '".$_POST['accphone'].
"', direccion = '".$_POST['accaddress'].
"', ciudad = '".$_POST['acccity'].
"', provincia = '".$_POST['accprovince'].
"', codigo_postal = '".$_POST['acccp'].
"' pais = '".$_POST['acccountry']."' ";
```

Por otro lado, no tienes clausula WHERE por lo que estás modificando TODOS los registros de la BBDD. ¿?.

Comment: Este código tiene muy serios problemas de seguridad, incluso si tuviera el WHERE, sería muy fácil inyectar código.

Comment: Pues era ese el problema, y si que se me había pasado lo del WHERE.

Comment: Acepta la respuesta y cierra la pregunta. Por favor, ten en cuenta lo que @Mariano te está apuntando acerca de [SQL Injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).